# C# Multi threading not starting worker/job?

Tags: c#

For some reason my threads are ignoring my job, it looks like anyone have any sort of idea why it is doing this? Help is very welcome and extremely appreciated, thank you. What this program is, is a ProxyChecker, because i've bought a bunch and will continue to do so of proxies with different user/passes etc, however some have expired

```
        static List<String> user = new List<String>();
        static List<String> pass = new List<String>();
        static List<String> ips = new List<String>();
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int threads = 4;
        loadips();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of threads to run (4 default):");
        threads = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Starting on " + threads + " threads...");
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CheckProxy), i);
        }
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public class MyIP
    {
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public bool AcceptsConnection { get; set; }
    }

    private static void CheckProxy(object state)
    {
        var u = user[0];
        var p = pass[0];
        var l = new List<MyIP>();
        Parallel.ForEach(l.ToArray(), (item) =>
        {
            string ip = getip();
            try
            {
                using (var client = new ProxyClient(ip, u, p))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ip, user, pass);
                    client.Connect();
                    item.AcceptsConnection = client.IsConnected;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                l.Remove(item);
            }
        });
        foreach (var item in l)
        {
            if (item.AcceptsConnection == true)
            {
                WriteToFile(user[0], pass[0]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(item.IP + " is " + (item.AcceptsConnection) + " accepts connections" + " doesn not accept connections");
        }
    }



 private static void loadips()
        {
            using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader("ips.txt"))
            {
                string line = null;
                while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    ips.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your app is more than likely finishing it's execution of `Main()` before anything else is finishing. Look into `System.Threading.WaitHandle` class.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't understand my code example... You should add the IP's to the list `l`, instead of a getip() method... So lose the `getip()` method

```
private static void CheckProxy(object state)
{
    var u = user[0];
    var p = pass[0];
    var l = new List<MyIP>();

    l.Add(new MyIP { IP = "192.168.1.1" });
    l.Add(new MyIP { IP = "192.168.1.2" });
    l.Add(new MyIP { IP = "192.168.1.3" });


    Parallel.ForEach(l.ToArray(), (ip_item) =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new ProxyClient(ip_item, u, p))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ip_item, user, pass);
                client.Connect();
                item.AcceptsConnection = client.IsConnected;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            lock(l)
                l.Remove(item);
        }
    });
    foreach (var item in l)
    {
        if (item.AcceptsConnection == true)
        {
            WriteToFile(user[0], pass[0]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(item.IP + " is " + (item.AcceptsConnection) + " accepts connections" + " doesn not accept connections");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh.... I see.... by the way i'm loading the ips from my text file line by line using stream reader i'll add it into the code example.. thanks

Comment: right, i have added each line to the list of l however it's saying i cannot convert from string to bool on the proxyclient when i changed ip to ip_item.

Comment: Right.. I changed it to string ip = ip_item.IP that seems to work now, however my program is still not running the CheckProxy statement.

Comment: this is my first time using multi threading, i've never used parallel if not thread queue then what?

Comment: Is there a problem that your `Main` method will be blocked when executing the Parallel.ForEach? The problem you're facing is that your program is already terminated (`Main` method ends) before the ThreadPool runs your method

Comment: Do you mean errors? If so there's none it's just skipping it, i've also tried just calling the function with i too

Comment: If you add a method to the ThreadPool, the other functiondoesn't wait on the ThreadPool to complete the job. It just continues executing. After you add it to the `ThreadPool` your `Main` method end, so you program does. This means, that your program ends sooner than the threadpool could startup the CheckProxy method.

Comment: Right, I understand. I added a break point and what it's doing is actually skipping the ProxyClient code and going straight to for each var item in 1, if item accepts connection etc, it then just returns false and finishes.

Comment: Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Still isn't completed anyone got any tips?